# Sort all files in folder and subfolder according to file basenames

Tags: python, file, sorting, directory

I've one root folder under which there are two folders, now I want to sort all files under root folder according to their names irrespective of sub-folder names.

Below is code which I tried, but problem here is that is sorting according to the name of subfolder under which the files are :

```
.../verify/AU1/APPLaunch_ftrace_au1.txt,
.../verify/AU1/Mp3BT_ftrace_au1.txt, 
.../verify/AU2/APPLaunch_ftrace_au2.txt,
.../verify/AU2/Mp3BT_ftrace_au2.txt

files_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(trace_folder, topdown = False):
    files_list.extend(join(root,f) for f in files)
files_list.sort()
```

what I would like to have is :

```
.../verify/AU1/APPLaunch_ftrace_au1.txt,
.../verify/AU2/APPLaunch_ftrace_au2.txt,
.../verify/AU1/Mp3BT_ftrace_au1.txt, 
.../verify/AU2/Mp3BT_ftrace_au2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a sort criteria to `sort` which only considers the basename of the file

```
files_list.sort(key=os.path.basename)
```

if you don't care about casing, that's also doable:

```
files_list.sort(key=lambda x : os.path.basename(x).lower())
```

Comment: Strange kind of sorting. Let `files_list` contain a file named "a". Then sorted  `files_list = ['/verify/AU1/APPLaunch_ftrace_au1.txt', '/verify/AU2/APPLaunch_ftrace_au2.txt','/verify/AU1/Mp3BT_ftrace_au1.txt', '/verify/AU2/Mp3BT_ftrace_au2.txt', 'a']`.

Comment: If letter case is irrelevant I would modify @Jean-FrançoisFabre to be `files_list.sort(key=lambda x: str.lower(os.path.basename(x)))`